# Where does sqlite file get stored on Mac?

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift

I've linked libsqlite3.dylib in my Xcode 6.6.1 application.  I'm not using Core data, I'm using FMDB.  Where can I find the .db or .sqlite file that gets created when my app is running?

I am pretty new to using a Mac, but I believe I searched everywhere on my machine using Finder and couldn't find any *.db or *.sqlite files.  When I run the app, it's retaining data between executions, so I know it's getting saved somewhere... but where?

Comment: Check your iphone simulator's document directory

Comment: A simple log statement in your code would show you the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all get your path of SQLite as below code.

```
-(NSString*)getDBPath
{
    NSArray *path =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentdirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentdirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wordDatabase.sqlite"];
}

-(void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded{
    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *DBPath = [self getDBPath];

    NSLog(@"Path == %@",DBPath);

    BOOL success = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:DBPath];
    if (!success) {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"wordDatabase.sqlite"];
        success = [filemanager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:DBPath error:&error];
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Error in creating database");
        }
    }
}
```

**YourParh :**  /Users/mspsys087/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AAECF3F8-1EFD-46D6-8B45-08A6BCE7A002/data/Documents/wordDatabase.sqlite

Now goto finder :

[image]

And Paste of your path in GO:

[image]

Click on GO then its display location of your database.

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful, thanks... but shouldn't doing a search for *.sqlite over my entire machine still find it?  If not, why?

Comment: I love you... For xamarin Mac to generate sqlite db path use: 
var dbPath = Path.Combine(NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User, true)[0], "database.db3");